# View transform rotation nullify image rendering effects in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, view

I've created a `UIButton` as follows (round button with shadow properties nothing too fancy):

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "4267B2")
    button.tintColor = .white
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "add").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 32
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 6
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
```

Purpose is to seem as an add button on click it rotates to form a cross button.

```
func handleClick() {
    button.isSelected = !newPostButton.isSelected
    let rotationDirection: CGFloat = button.isSelected ? 1: -1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.button.transform = self.button.transform.rotated(by: (rotationDirection * .pi/4))
    }
}
```

The issue  I encounter is when the animation occur for rotation the rotation works perfectly but the image provided for button `.withRendering:` is nullified as shown below:

[image: Initially]   [image: Finally]

Is there a fix? (with code no libraries please) I searched through the net but none had a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your button type to `.custom` instead of `.system`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, you saved a lot of time.